# How intelligent is Beppo, the supermonkey?

Tags: dc, superman

[Krypto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krypto) is said to be as intelligent as an average human being. Does that suggest [Beppo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beppo_%28comics%29) is a *genius*?

That would make him one of the greatest heroes (or villains, if he ever goes evil) on Earth.

Comment: Unfortunately Beppo the Supermonkey (along with Streaky the Supercat and Comet the Superhorse) no longer exists, as of Crisis on Infinite Earths. His intelligence is therefore nil.

Comment: “That would make him one of the greatest heroes... on Earth” — would it? Why?

Comment: Hi, Paul. High intelligence and powers similar to those of Superman, that's a lot of potential -- better than Gleek anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### During his early Silver Age appearances, [Beppo the Super-monkey](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Beppo_(Earth-One)) did not seem to possess superhuman levels of intelligence. His intellect seemed to be that of a young human child. In his first appearance in Superboy Vo1. #76 he didn't display any signs of super-intellect.

[image]

- Given the inconsistency of the writing back then, his depictions didn't vary too much from that range. He was never shown with super-HUMAN levels of intelligence. Superboy was forced to take Beepo into space and leave him there because he couldn't be controlled or apparently trained enough to be safe on Earth at the time.

[image]

- Strangely enough Krypto had been depicted with greater intelligence than that of the average dog and often displayed in the Silver Age with the intellect of the average Human being.

[image]

- After gaining telepathic ability working with the Legion of Superheroes, of the Super-Pets Beepo's communications still seemed to be the most primitive of the group.

[image]

- Comet the Super-horse in comparison, displayed advanced intellectual prowess and secretly held feelings for and had a relationship with Silver Age Supergirl.

[image]

- However, later appearances in the 1960s when Beppo was a member of the Legion of Super-Pets all of the pets displayed at least Human-level intellects which I attribute to the inconsistencies of Silver Age writing...and the need to have some sort of dialogue for the comic to progress.

[image]

Comment: "Comet the Super-horse... had a relationship with Silver Age Supergirl." The Silver Age was **weird**.